# Homoscedascity tests for Two-Way ANOVA (a factor and a covariate)

Tags: r, categorical-data, anova, ancova

I have the following formula:
`glm1 <- glm(y ~ g1 + g2, data = fish, family = binomial)`

> **y** is a binomial variable: num  1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ... #There is (1) or isn't (0) fish.
>   **g1** : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 1 1 4 1 2 1 1 3 ... #River's level.
>   **g2** : num  808 1110 754 421 568 535 570 690 668 556 ... #Precipitation (mL).

```
length(y)
>150
length(g1)
>150
length(g2)
>150
```

To test homoscedasticity, I tried:

```
bartlett.test(split(y, list(g1,g2))) #Then I get this:
>Error in bartlett.test.default(split(y, list(g1,  : 
>  there must be at least 2 observations in each group. #I think it's strange, because I've 3 vectors at the formula.
```

But my formula is y ~ g1+g2, then:

```
bartlett.test(y ~ g1+g2, data=fish) #Then I get this:
>Error in fligner.test.formula(y ~ g1 +  : 
> 'formula' should be of the form response ~ group
```

I also tried other tests:

```
leveneTest(y ~ g1+g2) #Then I get this:
>Error in leveneTest.formula(y ~ g1 + g2, data = fish) : 
> Levene's test is not appropriate with quantitative explanatory variables.
```

Finally, I tried this:

```
fligner.test(split(y, list(g1,g2)))
>Error in fligner.test.default(split(y, list(g1,  : 
> all groups must contain data  #Again, I think it's strange, because I've 3 vectors at the formula
```

**1. Is it compulsory that both g1 and g2 have to be factors (categorical variable) to test homoscedasticity?
2. How homoscedasticity can be tested in a formula like mine (y-num ~ g1-factor + g2-num) with Bartlett's, Levene's and Fligner's?**

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not a programming question - you should ask stats-related questions on Cross Validated (a stats-version of Stack Overflow). However, to save you some time, with logistic regression you don't need to test for homoscedasticity. Think about it. What would homo/heteroscedasticity mean in the context of logistic regression, since the reponse can only take 0 and 1 values?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!.
And in case it wasn't logistic, I wander if it is possible to test homoscedasticity in a formula like: y-num ~ g1-factor + g2-factor (+g3+...) or y-num ~ g1-factor + g2-num (+g3+...)

Comment: Should definitely be possible. I haven't used numerical goodness of fit tests in a while - most statisticians I've read recommend doing visual checks instead. Those are very easy: you can get your predicted values using `pred1 <- fitted(glm1)`, your residuals using `resids1 <- residuals(glm1)`, and then you can just plot them against each other using either `plot(pred1, resids1)` or `qplot(pred1, resids1)` if you're using `tidyverse`.

Comment: By the way, I am aware that I am testing errors distribution, binomial in this case. Having known that (or other kind of distribution), then it is known that such residuals haven't got either a normal distribution, independence or homoscedasticity. Then, why do many authors show graphics such as Residuals vs.Fitted and Q-Q Plots?.
Thank you again for your kindness in answering!.

Comment: The residuals *should* be independent though. That's one assumption common to all models I know of. You need the assumption of normality and homoscedasticity when you're modeling the data with gaussian likelihood, which is by far the most commonly used likelihood (i.e. that's what you use in standard linear regression, ANOVA, t-test, etc....). I haven't seen Q-Q plots for logistic regression. The fitted vs. residual plot you can still technically do, but the interpretation of it is different, and there's better diagnostics for model fit, e.g. the AUC-ROC curve.